# Weird behaviour of a logarithmic scales in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have here a scatter plot with 2 scales. The user can decide whether he needs a linear or a logarithmic scale via radio buttons for each axis. The default scale for y axis is `log` and for x - `linear`. This works perfectly. I am getting a nice graph with 7 values on each axis and on the y I have the values from 1 to 1000000.
I use the following code for the y axis:

```
d3.scaleLog()
           .domain([1, 9535511.8])
           .range([that.height, 1])
```

For the x axis:

```
d3.scaleLinear()
           .domain([1, 119.05])
           .range([1, that.width]);
```

Since x axis is linear.

Now it behaves weird when I change the `scale` of `x` hearing to the `change` event on the radio button. It still works but I get an ugly axis with the numbers 1 to 10 till the half of the axis and then 20 to 100 till the end. On the change method I'm doing something like this:

```
var xLg = d3.scaleLog()
                .domain([1, 119.05])
                .range([1, that.width]);
var xAxisLog = d3.axisBottom(xLg)
                .ticks(5)
                .tickFormat(function(d){ return d; });
d3.selectAll("g.axisX").transition().duration(100).call(xAxisLog);
```

- Is there anything wrong about acting this way in d3?
- Are there any ways to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Mike Bostock [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/issues/61), the given number of ticks is a guideline used by `d3.ticks` with no guarantee that the generated ticks array will be of the same length.

Try setting: `.ticks(10)`

Comment: But it cann't be that there isn't any appropriate way to just display the ticks on an axis in the best visualization tool in the world. Exact the same thing works perfectly for a domain of [1, 9535511.8] and it doesn't for this one: [1, 119.05]. I cann't understand why that should be an "expected behaviour".

Comment: Well, I do understand your dissatisfaction as I have run into quite the same problem. However, it is truly admissible that `d3.ticks` is considered as a low-level tool which does not worry about aesthetics.
The linked github issue's OP decreases ticks count in a loop until resulting ticks count becomes lower as a workaround.
My workaround was to compute an appropriate number of ticks *estimation* depending on the domain size (in pixels).